# VSCode “Find All” not looking in all files, only open files

Tags: visual-studio-code, findall

I am using VSCode for my Angular 8 project.
When using "*Find in Folder*" `(Ctrl+Shift+F)` within VSCode to find all instances of a text, it's only looking in openned files.
[Screenshot of the search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDNQ1.jpg)

I'am 100% sure my text is present in multiple files that are not open but nothing found by VSCode.

But "*Find in Folder*" is working for another Angular 8 project...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

Some of my folders and files were "controlled" (encrypted ?) by my company. A little briefcase appeared on folders and files icons.

I removed it using right click, "File property" and selecting "Personal" option (translation is approximative because my OS is in French).

Hope it will help someone !